# When function with for loop is called it only returns on value from dict.

Tags: python

I dont understand why this function - with for loop, only returns one value from a dict. when called:

```
my_dict = {"key1": 2, "key2": 3, "key3": 4}


def fun():
    for x in my_dict:
        return my_dict[x]

var = fun()
print var
```

How to make it return all the values that the loop produces? I know there are smarter ways, but im very new to Python and trying to understand how it functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you `return` a value from a function, the function breaks, and so the loop breaks.

You can append all the values to a list, then return that list:

```
def fun():
    L = []
    for x in my_dict:
        L.append(my_dict[x])
    return L

var = fun()
print var
```

This can also be done with a list comprehension:

```
def fun():
    return [my_dict[x] for x in my_dict]
```

Comment: Thx. now I understand a bit more :-)

Comment: I know it is a bit of a stupid question, but I'm very new to programming and Python and your answer made me understand a bit more how functions work.